# Rasterizing in QGIS 3.16 - Rasterlayer doesn't show up

Tags: qgis, raster, vector-layer, gdal-rasterize

I would like to transfer a vector-layer (containing the attribute "Polygon NN") to a raster.
After filling in all parameters and Rasterizing the vector layer, nothing shows up. I watched lots of tutorials and read other questions here, but unfortunately, nothing helped yet.
Some more information: The "Polygon_Gesamt" is the vector-layer I'd like to Rasterize. The Raster should be shaped exactly the same as the "Polygon_Gesamt". The Vector is created as a multiple-Polygon. Each polygon contains a different value safe in the attribute "Polygon NN".

The first question is: Why isn't anything showing up?
And the second one is: Is it possible to transfer the values of the attribute directly or do I have to transfer it some other way?

[image]

Comment: Your polygon layer is on a CRS EPSG:4937 while the output extent is defined on EPSG: 3035. I am not sure if GDAL rasterize reprojects the layer on-the-fly. Can you reproject your polygon onto EPSG: 3035 beforehand?